# Why Is ACCESS_ONCE so complex?

Tags: c, linux-kernel

The Linux ACCESS_ONCE macro is defined as follows:

```
#define ACCESS_ONCE(x) (*(volatile typeof(x) *)&(x))
```

I understand what this does, but wondered why it is so complex ? My understanding is it does the following:

1. Take address (create a temp pointer to) the variable of concern
2. Cast this to a volatile pointer of the same type
3. De-reference that pointer

Any ideas why this isn't implemented in a simpler fashion, say:

```
 #define ACCESS_ONCE(x) ((volatile typeof(x))(x))
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The ACCESS_ONCE macro is used in situations where a value is being retrieved from a storage location that is known (or suspected) to be volatile, but is not typed as such. The purpose is to retrieve the current value of the storage location in such a way as to defeat an optimising compiler that might otherwise cache the value in a register, or not even provide a storage location at all.

The construct as written applies the 'volatile' to the storage location indirectly by declaring a suitably typed pointer to that location. As per the C standard, this mandates that the `object be evaluated strictly according to the rules of the abstract machine`.

Your proposed modification would not apply `volatile` to the storage location, so it would not achieve this purpose. The value retrieval could be subject to optimisation.

Incidentally, I regard this as a model of conciseness for the stated purpose. I reserve `complex` for far worse things than this.

Comment: Thank you, David, for your clear & precise explanation.

Comment: Some more context: the C standards allow to assign the `volatile` qualifier to *data*, not to the *accesses* to the data. There is a good quantity of people who consider that this is stupid; among them, Linus. Additionally, `volatile` has some more problems, to the point that it's kinda-considered-harmful in the Linux kernel, multithread, etc. So, the technique in the ACCESS_ONCE macro (& friends) is a way to force an access with C volatile semantics only when it is needed, avoiding the disadvantages. Note that this was contentious enough to cause a GCC regression!

Answer (score 0):

A cast to volatile on a "simple" variable is basically useless - it won't change the underlying access semantics, so this is not what you want.

Comment: How do you know what he/she wants ?

Comment: if you cast anything to volatile, you'd probably expect to change the storage class of that anything to volatile.

It doesn't work like this, however.

Think of a cast as creating a temporary object of that wanted type (you wouldn't expect the underlying variable to change to a double if you'd cast an integer to double, would you?).